# Mutual information between multivariate random variables?

Tags: self-study, mutual-information, multivariate-distribution

I have read that mutual information only works with two random variables,
and that for 3 or more RVs there seems to be a variety of different measures (synergy, partial information decomposition, and others) each with some disadvantages.

My question: how does this relate to the "multivariate-ness" of RVs.
Suppose there are two multivariate RVS
$$
  \mathbf{X} = (X_1,X_2)
$$
and 
$$
  \mathbf{Y} = (Y_1,Y_2)
$$
From the point of calculat the mutual information between $\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{Y}$,
is it impossible because there are actually *four* random numbers $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ (and so synergy or some other measure has to be used)
or is it MI between these two multivarite RVs properly defined?

The problem for me is that in describing mutual information, authors say "random variable" without clarifying whether the RV can be (or must not be) multivariate.

Edit: as seen below, several strong people say this question is a duplicate of another question that I also asked. I believe it must be true, but still do not see much relation between the two questions yet!

Specifically, I think this one is about whether MI can apply to multivariate RVs or not.  The other one is a statement about "entropy involves distrubitions, whereas MI involves RVs".  That later statement is mysterious to me, because MI also involves distrubitions (joint and marginal). And it doesn't answer whether the distrubitions can be between multivariate RVs or not.

The other question is also not answered yet. Hopefully a kind person can answer one question, or the other, and then I will see how they are the same.

(Note, in math I am already aware that for example some particular theorems are instances of the triangle inequality. So a beginner could ask about the particular theorem and not understand that it is related to a question about the triangle inequality, but a good answer could help them see why.)

Comment: If this is a duplicate, I do not see how.  They _seem_ like different questions to me, but maybe a deeper understanding reveals that they are the same. 
Anyway, neigher question is answered right now.  Perhaps the answer can say why they are the same question.