# Entropy is a measure on distributions, mutual information is a measure on RVs

Tags: self-study, information-theory, mutual-information

In a lecture I read this statement, no explanation was given

> "Unlike entropy, mutual information is a measure on random variables, not on distributions"

Can anyone explain what this means?

From the definition, both entropy and mutual information are defined in terms of the probabilities
of random variables, so I have no understanding of it.

The statement is in this lecture, 
http://infotheorytcs.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/Lecture_3.pdf

p.10 in Exercise 3.2.10

Comment: Thinking about it, maybe part of what it means is this:  H(X) is calculated using a formula that involves p(x), so it could perhaps be notated H(p(x)).

The mutual information involves two variables. But it still depends on their distributions... so there is still soemthing I miss.

Comment: Many people say that this question is a dupliate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350011/mutual-information-between-multivariate-random-variables .   I do not see the relationship, though they must be correct.